# Passing Variables and Table Data to a Text File Using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need to create a text file, each line of which consists of formatted values taken from 3 different places. I am able to create the file and pass the static variable and user input variables to the file, but I cannot seem to pass the row data from the table to the file.

RoutingNum is a single cell
Chkdate and ChkNum are taken from user input
AcctNum and Amt are from a table <-------------this is the problem.

The table has only two columns

AcctNum and Amt are named ranges in the table.

Each line of the file should look like this:

```
linetext = _
    RoutingNum & _
    Format(AcctNum, "00000000000000") & _
    Format(ChkDate, "yymmdd") & _
    Format(ChkNum, "0000000000") & _
    Format(Amt, "00000000")
```

Here is what I have:

```
Dim strPath As String
strPath = wsEngine.Range("Path") & _
    Format(wsEngine.Range("ChkDate"), "yymmdd") & _
    Format(Time(), "hhmmss") & _
    ".txt"
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set a = fs.createtextfile(strPath)

linetext = _
    RoutingNum & _
    Format(AcctNum, "00000000000000") & _
    Format(ChkDate, "yymmdd") & _
    Format(ChkNum, "0000000000") & _
    Format(Amt, "00000000")

For i = 1 To wsAccts.Range("tbldata").Rows.Count
    a.WriteLine linetext
Next i

a.Close
```

I am unable to insert AcctNum or Amt into each line. The rest of linetext is working.

I could use help to loop through the table and insert the cell values from each row into linetext.

Comment: Use Option Explicit, that might help you see what is amiss. Linetext is not inside the loop. Amt is not a variable in VBA it is a named range on your sheet. To what does “tbldata” refer?

Comment: Placing LineText in the loop doesn't help (by itself), but I'll leave it there.

AcctNum and Amt are named ranges in tbldata. tbldata is the table with the two columns (AcctNum and Amt).

I am trying to pass named ranges AcctNum and Amt to the variables and that seems to be what isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs some modifications as below:

```
For i = 1 To wsAccts.Range("tbldata").Rows.Count

    AcctNum = wsAccts.Range("tbldata").Cells(i, 1).Value 'First column
    Amt = wsAccts.Range("tbldata").Cells(i, 2).Value 'Second column
    
    linetext = _
    RoutingNum & _
    Format(AcctNum, "00000000000000") & _
    Format(ChkDate, "yymmdd") & _
    Format(ChkNum, "0000000000") & _
    Format(Amt, "00000000")
    
    a.WriteLine linetext
    
Next i
```

You obviously need to map appropriate variable to fill data from table.

Comment: Now the text "AcctNum" and "Amt" are inserted. Progress, but not the data. 

AcctNum and Amt are the named ranges of the columns in the table (if that matters) and I have them declared as String.

Changing the variable names do not solve the issue, it merely inserts the new variable name (i.e. AccountNumber rather than AcctNum).

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

I needed to place both linetext, and the variables AcctNum and Amt, inside the loop.

It works perfectly. Thank you.